Store files getting undefined when refreshing the page
Store files getting undefined when refreshing the browser,
public getStateFile = (): StateFiles => {
return this.store.selectSnapshot(StateFileState).stateFile;};

this is the store operation for getting the state file,
    const stateFile = this.storeOp.getStateFile();
 this.ini = this.storeOp.getINIData();

this is the code  I am retrieving the state file and this.ini  from the store, it is called in the ngOnInit() lifecycle hook, ini also getting undefined

What store are you referring to? Are you using NgRX? Or did you create your own store? If it's your own store, how exactly are you persisting the data?

I am using NgRx store

dispatch action before calling your function in the ngOnInit() to make sure the data is fetching, you can use the redux tool to inspect the data flow and debug your action/state ;)

This is expected, ngrx stores the data in memory, when you refresh the screen the variables are lost.
If you want a localStorage implementation of ngrx, try the below article.
How to add NgRx Store Slices into LocalStorage

This is expected behavior, the NgRx store is in-memory and resets on refresh. It is possible to persist the store in the local storage and load from the local storage on init, you can write your own reducer. You can also use a third party library to make this easier, for example https://github.com/btroncone/ngrx-store-localstorage.
